# cakephp search criteria using related models

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I'm having an ongoing issue with dealing with getting lists of items based on search criteria on different but related tables.  I need to have a clear idea of how to deal with this type of situation. Here is my simplest example:

if I have an Agency Model (using a table called referral with a primary key of r_num and an Agent Model using a table called agents, the agents table contains a foreign key of r_num linking to the Agencies, The agency can have many Agents:

**Table:  referral**

```
r_num int -- primary key auto incremented
r_company varchar(50) -- the name of the agency
... other fields don't matter
```

**Table: agents**

```
a_num int -- primary key auto incremented
r_num int -- foreign key to the referral table
a_lname varchar(50) -- agent's last name
a_fname varchar(50) -- agent's first name
a_email varchar(50) -- agent's email
```

**Models:**

```
class Agency extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Agency';   
    var $useTable = 'referral';
    var $primaryKey = 'r_num'; 

    var $hasMany = array(
         'Agent' => array(
         'className' => 'Agent',
         'foreignKey' => 'r_num',
        'order' => 'Agent.a_lname DESC',
        'dependent'=> true
         )  
     ); 
}
class Agent extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Agent';    
    var $primaryKey = 'a_num'; 

}
```

All I want is to return a list using $this->Agency->find('all') using conditions from a search form, which includes agent first name, agent last name, agent email.  I need a list of Agency company names and ids but the search criteria is based on the agents.  I have several different models that will use this, so I need documentation on how this can work.  What I've tried based on what I've found online is this in the AgencyController which works but it is a hack that won't work on some of my more complicated cases:  I need to do this without making multiple calls, since some of my tables will return huge numbers of rows, and using this technique on those queries takes several minutes.

```
class AgenciesController extends AppController {
   var $helpers = array ('Html','Javascript', 'Form', 'Paginator', 'Ajax', 'Phoneformat');
   var $name = 'Agencies';
   var $components = array('RequestHandler', 'RentalValidation'); 

   var $uses = array('Agency', 'Agent');

    function index() {
      $criteria =  $this->postConditions($this->data);

      if (empty($criteria)){
         $arrArgs = $this->passedArgs;
         unset($arrArgs['page']);
         $criteria = $arrArgs;
      }
      $searchcriteria = array();
      foreach (array('Agency.r_state', 'Agency.r_company') as $item ) {
         $itemvalue = '';
         if (isset($criteria[$item])){
            $itemvalue = $criteria[ $item];
            if (!empty($itemvalue)) {
               $searchcriteria[$item . " LIKE "] = '%' .  $itemvalue .'%';
            }
         }
      }
      foreach (array('Agent.a_lname', 'Agent.a_email') as $item ) {
         $itemvalue = '';
         if (isset($criteria[$item])){
            $itemvalue = $criteria[ $item];
            if (!empty($itemvalue)) {
               $agent_rnums = $this->Agent->find('list', 
               array('conditions' => 
                    array($item . " LIKE " => '%'. $itemvalue .'%'), 
                         'fields' => 'Agent.r_num'));
               $searchcriteria['r_num'] = $agent_rnums;
            }
         }
      }
      $this->set('passedCriteria', $criteria);
      $data = $this->paginate('Agency', $searchcriteria);   
      if (count($data) == 1) {
         $referralid = $data[0]['Agency']['id'];
         $this->redirect(array('action' => 'edit', $referralid));
      }
      $this->set('agencies', $data);
   }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you do it the other way?

- Get all Agents matching the desired conditions
- do a Set::combine to get the agency_ids (and have it uniquified)
- do query with IN agency_ids

that way there would be only 2 sql calls

Comment: This is what the code above does now.  $agent_rnums is the agents matching the conditions, and then I add that array to the search criteria which automatically converts to an IN, so it does do 2 SQL calls.  There is something called deepfind, that is supposed to combine these items and make it more efficient, I haven't been able to get that to work yet.